# Enviar mail através de Lua

Tags: lua, email

Quero enviar um simples mail em Lua, utilizei o exemplo na [documentação oficial](http://w3.impa.br/~diego/software/luasocket/smtp.html), e devolve me sempre `nil`. Exemplo:

```
-- load the smtp support
local smtp = require("socket.smtp")

from = "<luasocket@example.com>"

rcpt = {
  "<fulano@example.com>",
  "<beltrano@example.com>",
  "<sicrano@example.com>"
}

mesgt = {
 headers = {
   to = "Fulano da Silva <fulano@example.com>",
   cc = '"Beltrano F. Nunes" <beltrano@example.com>',
   subject = "My first message"
},
body = "I hope this works. If it does, I can send you another 1000  copies."
}

r, e = smtp.send{
 from = from,
 rcpt = rcpt, 
 source = smtp.message(mesgt)
}
```

Diz:

> host or service not provided, or not know

Comment: Não gera nenhum erro? Chega enviar? Eu acho que só isto realmente não vai resolver. Você precisa definir e autenticar no servidor. Este exemplo só funciona se circunstância específica, ele não está lá para resolver qualquer situação.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Talvez isso possa ajudar:

```
-- load the smtp support
local smtp = require("socket.smtp")

from = "<coloque_o_seu_email_aqui_nao_use_o_de_outras_pessoas@xxx.com>"

rcpt = {
  "<coloque_um_email_aqui_nao_use_o_de_outras_pessoas@xxx.com>",
  "<coloque_um_email_aqui_nao_use_o_de_outras_pessoas@xxx.com>",
  "<coloque_um_email_aqui_nao_use_o_de_outras_pessoas@xxx.com>"
}

mesgt = {
 headers = {
   to = "Fulano da Silva <coloque_um_email_aqui_nao_use_o_de_outras_pessoas@xxx.com>",
   cc = '"Beltrano F. Nunes" <coloque_um_email_aqui_nao_use_o_de_outras_pessoas@xxx.com>',
   subject = "My first message"
},
body = "I hope this works. If it does, I can send you another 1000  copies."
}

r, e = smtp.send{
 from = from,
 rcpt = rcpt, 
 source = smtp.message(mesgt)
 user = "usuario_valido_em_algum_servidor_de_email_que+voce_tenha_acesso",
 password = "senhaqui",
 server = "servidor_smtp_onde_voce_tenha_acesso_smtp.google.com_por_exemplo",
 port = 465, -- pode ser outra porta
 create = sslCreate
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Lua/SendMail.lua).

Não sei se mandaria sem criptografia neste caso. Não sei se essa biblioteca é completa. Ela não fala nada de SSL e sem esse protocolo vai ser difícil usar algum servidor hoje em dia.

Se você ler a documentação, verá que existem outras coisas que precisam ser feitas. Só copiar exemplo pronto não resolve tudo. Tem que estudar o material existente e adaptar ao que você precisa.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, tenho o seguinte erro ao utilidar o servidor smtp. Diz "host or service not provided, or not know"

Comment: É exatamente o que eu achei que era.

Comment: Mas tanto os dados do server, user e password estao correctos.

Comment: Não sei, afinal você não mostrou. Mas é o que eu falei, provavelmente não há suporte SSL nesta biblioteca, aí você teria problemas em quase todos os servidores.

Comment: Nao chega a enviar, na documentaçao nao encontro, so com este codigo nao vai funcionar.

Comment: Eu acho que não vai mesmo, acho que não tem suporta a SSL e quase todos servidores exigem. Veja se acha algum que não exige para fazer o teste.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11070623/lua-send-mail-with-gmail-account Talvez isto pode ajudar.

Comment: Se te ajuda, ótimo.